# Where can I find extended HTML reporters for Simpletest?

Tags: php, unit-testing, user-interface, simpletest

I am using [Simpletest](http://www.simpletest.org/) as my unit test framework for the PHP site I am currently working on. I like the fact that it is shipped with a simple HTML reporter, but I would like a bit more advanced reporter.

I have read the reporter API documentation, but it would be nice to be able to use an existing reporter, instead of having to do it yourself.

Are there any good extended HTML reporters or GUI's out there for Simpletest?

Tips on GUI's for PHPUnit would also be appreciated, but my main focus is Simpletest, for this project. I have tried [Cool PHPUnit Test Runner](http://cool.sourceforge.net/), but was not convinced.

Answer (score 1):

For SimpleTest I can't say I've ever found any "better" test reporters, so you may have to just buckle down and hack together some quick HTML/PHP for what you need.

As for PHPUnit, there's [PHPUnit2_HTML_Runner](http://www.defusion.org.uk/code/phpunit2-html-runner/), but it is far from ideal.  However, if you're willing to set up a continuous integration server like [Xinc](http://code.google.com/p/xinc/) or [phpUnderControl](http://www.phpundercontrol.org/about.html) you can get two very nice, very detailed automated testing interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Does SimpleTest output JUnit XML style reports? If it does, you should be able to integrate it into [CruiseControl](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/) or [Bamboo](http://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo/).